# repaint() duplicates a sibling component. Why?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm experimenting with `javax.swing`. Here's a simple task I was going to do: to make a circle change color once a button (a sibling component) is pressed. Here's my code. I'm enthusiastic about design patterns so you see all these singletons, builders, and whatnot (I hope you don't mind)

```java
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyUI ui = new MyUI();
        ui.display();
    }
}
```

```java
public class MyUI {
    public void display() {
        UIUtil.getUIBuilder()
                .withButton(SOUTH, () -> {
                    JButton button = new JButton("click me!");
                    button.setFont(new Font(SANS_SERIF, BOLD, 28));
                    button.setSize(150, 50);
                    button.addMouseListener(MouseListeningPanel.getInstance());
                    return button;
                })
                .withPanel(CENTER, MouseListeningPanel::getInstance)
                .withFrameSize(300, 300)
                .withDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
                .visualize();
    }
}
```

```java
public class MouseListeningPanel extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
    public static final MouseListeningPanel INSTANCE = new MouseListeningPanel();
    private Color startColor = UIUtil.getRandomColor();
    private Color endColor = UIUtil.getRandomColor();
    private MouseListeningPanel() {}
    public static MouseListeningPanel getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D twoDGraphics = (Graphics2D) g;
        GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(0, 0, startColor, getMiddle(), getMiddle(), endColor);
        twoDGraphics.setPaint(gradient);
        twoDGraphics.fillOval(calculateX(), calculateY(), calculateWidth(), calculateWidth());
    }

    private float getMiddle() {
        return getWidth() / 2f;
    }

    private int calculateX() {
        return getWidth() / 2 - calculateWidth() / 2;
    }

    private int calculateY() {
        return getHeight() / 2 - calculateWidth() / 2;
    }

    private int calculateWidth() {
        return Math.min(getWidth(), getHeight()) / 2;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        startColor = UIUtil.getRandomColor();
        endColor = UIUtil.getRandomColor();
        repaint();
    }

    // dummy implementations for other MouseListener methods
    // I can't extend JPanel and MouseAdapter at the same time so I have to provide them
}
```

```java
public class UIUtil {

    public static UIBuilder getUIBuilder() {
        return new UIBuilder();
    }
    public static UIBuilder getUIBuilder(Supplier<Container> contentPaneSupplier) {
        return new UIBuilder(contentPaneSupplier);
    }
    public static Color getRandomColor() {
        int red = Util.randomInt(255);
        int green = Util.randomInt(255);
        int blue = Util.randomInt(255);
        return new Color(red, green, blue);
    }

    public static SimpleRectangle getRandomRectangle(int parentWidth, int parentHeight) {
        return getRandomRectangle(parentWidth, parentHeight, 0.5F);
    }

    public static SimpleRectangle getRandomRectangle(int parentWidth, int parentHeight, float recDimensionToParentDimensionRatio) {
        int x = Util.randomInt(parentWidth);
        int y = Util.randomInt(parentHeight);
        int width = Util.randomInt((int) (parentWidth * recDimensionToParentDimensionRatio));
        int height = Util.randomInt((int) (parentHeight * recDimensionToParentDimensionRatio));
        return new SimpleRectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

    public record SimpleRectangle(int x, int y, int width, int height) {}

    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class UIBuilder {
        private final JFrame frame;
        private final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        {
            frame = new JFrame();
            this.withFrameSize(300, 300)
            .withDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        public UIBuilder(@NotNull Supplier<Container> contentPaneSupplier) {
            Objects.requireNonNull(contentPaneSupplier);
            frame.setContentPane(contentPaneSupplier.get());
        }

        public UIBuilder withButton(@NotNull String position, @NotNull Supplier<JButton> buttonSupplier) {
            Stream.of(position, buttonSupplier).forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);
            JButton button = buttonSupplier.get();
            frame.getContentPane().add(position, button);
            return this;
        }

        public UIBuilder withPanel(@NotNull String position, @NotNull Supplier<JPanel> panelSupplier) {
            Stream.of(position, panelSupplier).forEach(Objects::requireNonNull);
            JPanel panel = panelSupplier.get();
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
            frame.getContentPane().add(position, scrollPane);
            return this;
        }

        public UIBuilder withFrameSize(int width, int height) {
            checkAgainstScreenSize(width, height);
            int x = (screenSize.width - width) / 2;
            int y = (screenSize.height - height) / 2;
            frame.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
            return this;
        }

        private void checkAgainstScreenSize(int width, int height) {
            if (screenSize.width < width) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Frame width cannot be greater than screen width");
            } else if (screenSize.height < height) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Frame height cannot be greater than screen height");
            }
        }

        public UIBuilder withDefaultCloseOperation(int windowConstant) {
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(windowConstant);
            return this;
        }

        public void visualize() {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

It *kind of* works, but here's the snag: once I press the button, it gets cloned, and the copy is put in the `NORTH` section of the pane. I can't imagine why Java did that

[image]

Since regular resizing doesn't produce that result and `mouseClicked()` only sets colors and calls `repaint()`, `repaint()` is the only suspect. I checked the doc for the method

> Repaints **this** component

*This!* The button is not "this", is it? The button is a sibling, not a component of the panel. "This" must refer to the panel itself, and its `paintComponent()` doesn't add any buttons

Why is it happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: You'll probably need  a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Don't forget to add `super.paintComponent(...)` as the first statement in your painting method to make sure the background is cleared.

Comment: Ah `button.setSize(150, 50);` no and `frame.setBounds(x, y, width, height);` no and actually `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();` is erroneous when determining the viewable area of the screen (task bars any one?) and `pack` and `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` will actually do what you're trying to do ... just better

Comment: @MadProgrammer sorry, but I have no idea what you just said

Comment: @camickr thank you! But how is the lack of that statement connected to that button issue?

Comment: I already stated: *to make sure the background is cleared.* Swing painting is complicated. When a component is opaque it is guaranteed to paint the background first. By forgetting that statement the background not cleared. I don't know the internals of why the button would be painted twice but I do know when you don't clear the background you can get painting artifacts.

Comment: @JoreJoh `JFrame@pack` will pack the frame decorations around the content, so that the view area of the content will be based on their `preferredSize`. `JFrame#setLocationRelativeTo(null)` will centre position the window (on the default screen), taking into consideration the things like the task bar (on Windows) and the dock and menu bar on MacOS - unlike the solution you've been trying to hobble together